# If $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $|f(x)| \leq ||x||^{2}$, then, $f$ is differentiable at the origin.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$, I want to prove that if $f$ satisfies $|f(x)| \leq ||x||^{2}$. Then, $f$ is differentiable at the origin. So far, I try to reduce this problem to the case $n=2$, that is $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $|f(x_{1},x_{2})| \leq x_1^{2}+ x_2^{2}$. And according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), I need to prove that there exists a linear map $J:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\lim_{(x_{1},x_{2}) \rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)-J(x_1,x_2)|}{\|(x_1,x_2)\|_{\mathbb{R}^2}}=0$$.

So by taking $J: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ equal to the linear map zero I got

$$\frac{|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)|}{\sqrt{x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}}}.$$ But as $f(0,0)=0$ by the first answer we got that $$\frac{|f(x_1,x_2)-f(0,0)|}{\sqrt{x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}}}=\frac{|f(x_1,x_2)|}{\sqrt{x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}}} \leq \frac{(x_{1}^{2} + x_{2}^{2})}{\sqrt{x_1^{2}+x_2^{2}}}.$$ But limit of the last term of this inequality is zero as $(x_{1}, x_{2})$ aproaches to zero.

And in this step is where maybe I need to use my hypothesis $|f(x_{1},x_{2})| \leq x_1^{2}+ x_2^{2}$. But Im run out of ideas about how to proceed from here. Also Im not sure if the trick changes for $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: are you sure it is $|f(x_{1},x_{2})| \leq x^{2}+ y^{2}$?

Comment: @311411 Yes. Well, the original problem states  it is $|f(x)| \leq ||x||^{2}$. And $||x||^{2}=(\sqrt(x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}))^{2}$, right? For $x=(x_{1}, x_{2})$

Comment: Watch your title again....

Comment: Why do you think this is true? What if equality holds? Try drawing a graph.

Comment: You should decide to write either $(x_1,x_2)$ or $(x,y)$ for the points of $\mathbb R^2$. You use both in the same inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, you only miss the final step. You can also do it for arbitrary $n$.

Let  us first observe that $\lvert f(0) \rvert \le \lVert 0 \rVert^2 = 0$, thus $f(0) = 0$.

As you say, let us take $J$ to be the zero map. Then
$$\frac{|f(x)-f(0)-J(x)|}{\|x\|} = \frac{|f(x)|}{\|x\|} \le \frac{\|x\|^2}{\|x\|} = \|x\| . $$
Thus
$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{|f(x)-f(0)-J(x)|}{\|x\|}  = 0 .$$

Note that this also works if we assume that $\lvert f(x) \rvert \le \lVert x \rVert^r$ for some $r > 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just posted my solution by editing my question.  Nice observation about picking $r>1$. Wondering if you can check it out my answer and verify if its right?

Comment: @Sok It is correct now. I also made an update of my answer to make question and answer more compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(\underline 0)=0$. You can prove this by contradiction (i.e. by assuming $f(\underline 0)=l\ne 0$ and concluding that for no non-zero value $l$ do we have $|l|<||x||$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$).